# JavaScript Create substring from IndexOf not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to trim the values of an `href` before and after the domain name using JavaScript. For example, `http://www.google.com/about-us` should be trimmed to `www.google.com`.

```js
var str = "http://www.google.com/about-us";
var str_before = str.replace("http://","");
document.write(str_before); // Returns ("www.google.com/about-us")

// Trim everything after the domain name

var link = str_before.substring(0, str_before.indexOf('/'));
document.write(link); // Returns "www.google.com/about-uswww.google.com"
```

I don't know why this is happening.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href = str; a.host; // "www.google.com"`

Comment: Nope, it's `document.write` tricking you. Use `console.log` to check the results of your code.

Comment: do not use document.write, forget it exists. Why do beginner courses teach people to use it, it is not the 90/00s any more.

Comment: @epascarello Not only some courses, but even MDN examples often use `dw()`. I've left feedback for Mozilla a couple of years ago about using `dw()` in examples, but not sure, if its use has been decreased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the output of the previous `document.write` concatenated with the output of the second `document.write`. If you add a line break to the output, you will see the real output as two lines and you will see that the result is in fact correct.

Try the code snippet below:

```js
var str = "http://www.google.com/about-us";
var str_before = str.replace("http://","");
document.write(str_before); // Outputs "www.google.com/about-us"

// Trim everything after the domain name
var link = str_before.substring(0, str_before.indexOf('/'));

//add line break to the output
document.write( '<br />' );

//output the resulting link
document.write( link );
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was overlooking the document.write() line I had in place.